# InternetExplorer - delete specific element from IE.Document

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer, mshtml

I am using VBA to automate the pulling of reports from a structured web page.

I have the following code block which changes the dropdown element for each element in an array"

```
With IE
For Each itemName In itemNames()
i = i + 1
Module2.check_and_wait_for_item ("cboDistrict")
Set Dropdown = .document.getElementsByName("cboDistrict")(0)
Dropdown.Value = itemValues(i)
Dropdown.FireEvent ("onchange")



check_and_wait_for_item ("cmdRptPreview")
Set btnPreview = .document.getElementsByName("cmdRptPreview")(0)
btnPreview.Click

check_and_wait_for_item ("BtnExport")
Set HTMLDoc = .document
write_file_to_dir HTMLDoc, "C:\Users\user\Documents\____thing\", itemName & ".html"
.GoBack

Next itemName
End With
```

The problem arises with IE.GoBack. I have a function that checks if JavaScript has finished executing by looping while a particular element is not present on the page. "Going back" puts the element back on the page even though the JavaScript event has not finished running.

This is why I want to delete the old "cmdRptPreview" element before I have my function check if JavaScript event has finished running.

Is there a way to do so? Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to remove the Node containing the element being checked by JavaScript waiter function. 
After .GoBack:

```
check_and_wait_for_item ("cmdRptPreview")
.document.getElementsByName("cmdRptPreview")(0).ParentNode.RemoveChild .document.getElementsByName("cmdRptPreview")(0)
```

Comment: Congratulation. I suggest you to try to mark this answer as an accepted answer for this question after 48 hrs, when it is available to mark. It can help other community members in future in similar kind of issues. Thanks for your understanding.